# How to reloadCells correctly

Tags: ios, ios5, uitableview

I have a navigation menu in a UITableView.

My cells are loaded with the following:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        UIView *topSplitterBar = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.bounds.size.width, 1)];
        topSplitterBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:62.0/255.0 green:69.0/255.0 blue:85.0/255.0 alpha:1];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:topSplitterBar];
    }

    // Set a boolean to determine if the item in the menu is the currently displayed VC on the main stack
    BOOL currentDisplayed = NO;


    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:196.0/255.0 green:204.0/255.0 blue:218.0/255.0 alpha:1];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18.0f];
    cell.textLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:27.0/255.0 green:31.0/255.0 blue:41.0/255.0 alpha:1];
    cell.textLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);

    UIView *selectedBg = [[UIView alloc] init];
    selectedBg.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:50.0/255.0 green:56.0/255.0 blue:73.0/255.0 alpha:1];
    selectedBg.clipsToBounds = YES;
    UIView *topSplitterBar2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.bounds.size.width, 1)];
    topSplitterBar2.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    [selectedBg addSubview:topSplitterBar2];
    [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:selectedBg];

    // Configure the cell...
    if (indexPath.section == 0 ) {
        if ([self.slidingViewController.topViewController isKindOfClass:[MESProfileViewController class]]) {
            currentDisplayed = YES;
        }
        cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"LMDisplayName", @"Left Menu - displayname");
    } else {
        switch ( indexPath.row ) {
            case 0: {
                if ([self.slidingViewController.topViewController isKindOfClass:[MESHomeViewController class]]) {
                    currentDisplayed = YES;
                } 
                cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"LMGames", @"Left Menu - Games");
                break ;
            }
            case 1: {
                cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"LMShare", @"Left Menu - Share");
                break ;
            }
            case 2: {
                cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"LMRate", @"Left Menu - Rate");
                break ;
            }
            case 3: {
                if ([self.slidingViewController.topViewController isKindOfClass:[MESSettingsViewController class]]) {
                    currentDisplayed = YES;
                }
                cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"LMSettings", @"Left Menu - Settings");
                break ;
            }
            case 4: {
                cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"LMHelp", @"Left Menu - Help");
                break ;
            }
            case 5: {
                cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"LMLogout", @"Left Menu - Log out");
                break ;
            }
        }
    }

    if (currentDisplayed) {
        // This is for the current item that is being displayed
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:50.0/255.0 green:56.0/255.0 blue:73.0/255.0 alpha:1];
        UIImage *arrowImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedArrow"];
        UIImageView *arrow = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(240, 10, arrowImage.size.width, arrowImage.size.height)];
        arrow.image = arrowImage;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:arrow];
    } else {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:75.0/255.0 green:83.0/255.0 blue:102.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        NSLog(@"%@",cell.textLabel.text);
        NSLog(@"%@",cell.contentView.subviews);
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Then within the didSelectCell I reload a set of cells (which can be shown as the current cell) to change the background.

```
NSIndexPath* displayNameRow = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
NSIndexPath* gamesRow = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1];
NSIndexPath* settingsRow = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:1];
NSArray* rowsToReload = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:displayNameRow, gamesRow, settingsRow, nil];
[weakSelf.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:rowsToReload withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

What I am finding is that the UIView *topSplitterBar is being created again and added to the cell.contentView each time the cell is being reloaded?

I would of thought a reload of the cell would clear all subviews and create from scratch. How should I change this implementation to not continue to add these views. I also have another UIImageView for an arrow added if it is the current cell, with the same effect as above so eventually I have cells with a lot of additional views not needed.

Background:
This is a side view controller (sliding in) menu table view. The selected cell shows that this current selection is already displayed as the main top view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your implementation of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, so that it doesn't add subviews again and again. I have written a draft implementation with comments.

```
//Here you might get a reusable cell with dequeuing so your subviews are already there, just do customization on the subviews
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    //If you haven't got a reusable cell create a new one with all default subview properties
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    UIView *topSplitterBar = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.bounds.size.width, 1)];
    topSplitterBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:62.0/255.0 green:69.0/255.0 blue:85.0/255.0 alpha:1];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:topSplitterBar];
}

//Do all your customization afterwards, identifying cells based on indexPath
...
```

This is a neat answer (not the accepted one) regarding the issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/3490460/837244 the accepted answer says solution B will work but actually it will be adding subviews repeatedly, as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Thanks, but this appears to actually stop that view being added at all.

Comment: why? you add it in the statement `[cell.contentView addSubview:topSplitterBar];` inside if block

Comment: I have updated the question with the full code for the method to help explain what is being done here

Comment: On the first load the cell is nil therefore that view is not loaded.

Comment: if the cell is nil, then you create a new cell with the subview added inside if statement. Initially there are no available cells, you add them inside cell==nil if block, after some dequeuable cells are created you don't add subviews again but only change the content of subviews. So there shouldn't be addSubview methods called after the if block.

Comment: On the first load of the application if I step through the process the if(cell==nil) is skipped. Is the line above not creating the cell itself..?

Comment: the cells you create are added to queue for reuse later. when you call dequeue if it is successfull you get one of those cells with the previous data. If it is not successful (cell is nil) then you create a new cell with reuse identifier to be possibly used later.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure I understand you. I have copied my code into the question as an example. I load the subview in the if statement now. When I load the app the topSplitterBar is not in the tablecell as it was before? When I add a breakpoint and step through even when the first cell is being created the cell is not nil so it does not go into the if statement and create the subview.

Comment: do you have a prototype cell with same identifier in the storyboard, that can be why it doesn't return nil. Have a look at this question for more explanation http://stackoverflow.com/a/10255020/837244

Comment: Yes you are right, as I am creating in code I needed to remove the identifier from the storyboard cell as this was causing the cell to be created. AWESOME! One other item, if I create a view in the if statement (cell==nil) how can I access this view outside of the if statement later on. I.e. to set it to hidden and not hidden?

Comment: I accepted this answer and created another question for the next part here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16464898/updating-cells-with-uiimageview-to-show-currently-selected-item