# Updating cells with UIImageView to show currently selected item

Tags: ios, ios5, uitableview

I am using a sliding view controller which holds the main controller on top and a slide left menu controller.

The controller on the left works as the menu like Facebook/Pintrest apps etc. It is a `UITableView` on the left.

Here is my setup:
**cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MainMenuCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    UIView *topSplitterBar = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.bounds.size.width, 1)];
    topSplitterBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:62.0/255.0 green:69.0/255.0 blue:85.0/255.0 alpha:1];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:topSplitterBar];

    UIImage *arrowImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedArrow"];
    self.arrowSelectedView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(240, 10, arrowImage.size.width, arrowImage.size.height)];
    self.arrowSelectedView.image = arrowImage;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.arrowSelectedView];
    self.arrowSelectedView.hidden = YES;
}

//////
// ADDITIONAL GLUE CODE HERE TO SET LABELS ETC....
//////

if (currentDisplayed) {
    // This is for the current item that is being displayed
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:50.0/255.0 green:56.0/255.0 blue:73.0/255.0 alpha:1];
    self.arrowSelectedView.hidden = NO;
} else {
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:75.0/255.0 green:83.0/255.0 blue:102.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    self.arrowSelectedView.hidden = YES;
}

NSLog(@"%@",cell.contentView.subviews);
return cell;
```

There are a total of 7 cells in 2 sections for the table view. One cell in section 1 (0) and the rest in section 2 (1). There are three cells which show a main controller on the top. Once they are selected I would like to update the table view to show an arrow next the cell like this:
[image]

Here is the example code for: **didSelectRowAtIndexPath**

```
        UIViewController *newTopViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ProfileVC"];

        __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

        [self.slidingViewController anchorTopViewOffScreenTo:ECRight animations:nil onComplete:^{
            CGRect frame = weakSelf.slidingViewController.topViewController.view.frame;
            weakSelf.slidingViewController.topViewController = newTopViewController;
            weakSelf.slidingViewController.topViewController.view.frame = frame;
            [weakSelf.slidingViewController resetTopViewWithAnimations:nil onComplete:^{
                NSIndexPath* displayNameRow = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
                NSIndexPath* gamesRow = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1];
                NSIndexPath* settingsRow = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:1];
                NSArray* rowsToReload = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:displayNameRow, gamesRow, settingsRow, nil];
                [weakSelf.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:rowsToReload withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
            }];
        }];
```

**Issue/Question**
So I have a strange issue here, were if I click on a different cell it works the arrow is shown on the other cell. Then again this works for 2 more times, then the third times it randomly decides to show the uiimageview on another cell.

Even if I step through the cell creation process I see for that specific cell (the incorrectly displayed one) the boolean for currentDisplayed is set to NO, so it doesn't change the arrowSelectedView to not hidden yet it does somehow? I log out the subviews and can see that it is randomly not Hidden anymore even though for that specific cell it is not set to not hidden, so I am thinking this is implemented incorrectly somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue here is that in -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: you're creating a new image view every time you create a new cell, then storing it into a single ivar. The call to set or hide the image view later in that method is not guaranteed (indeed is actually quite unlikely) to be addressing the same image view that was added into that particular cell's content view.

A more convenient place to store it would be in a subclass of UITableViewCell's view like so:

```
@interface CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (strong, readwrite) UIImageView *imageAccessory;

@end

@implementation CustomTableViewCell

@end

@implementation YourClass

- (id)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MainMenuCell";

  CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if (nil == cell) {
    cell = [[CustomTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    UIView *topSplitterBar = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.bounds.size.width, 1)];
    topSplitterBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:62.0/255.0 green:69.0/255.0 blue:85.0/255.0 alpha:1];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:topSplitterBar];

    UIImage *arrowImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedArrow"];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(240, 10, arrowImage.size.width, arrowImage.size.height)];
    imageView.image = arrowImage;
    cell.accessoryImage = imageView;
    [cell.contentView addSubview: cell.accessoryImage];
    cell.accessoryView.hidden = YES;
  }

  if (currentDisplayed) {
      // This is for the current item that is being displayed
      cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:50.0/255.0 green:56.0/255.0 blue:73.0/255.0 alpha:1];
      cell.accessoryImage.hidden = NO;
  } else {
      cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:75.0/255.0 green:83.0/255.0 blue:102.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
      cell.accessoryImage.hidden = YES;
  }

  return cell;
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks, however this doesn't seem to show it. Does the accessoryView sit behind the content view perhaps?

Comment: Checked this manually, and you're right - there are a few issues. One, the imageView never gets its image set (I didn't copy and paste right!), two the cell doesn't get redrawn. The didSelectRowAtIndexPath will need to tell the tableView to manually redraw the table cell. I've updated the code above to fix the first issue. Thirdly, you'll also need to keep track of which indexPath is being selected - I assume that's what currentDisplayed is for, but its not actually in any of the code provided.

Comment: The other issue I have is that the actual view is off screen, if you check my image in question. I need to move the accessory view but changing the frame doesnt seem to affect it?

Comment: Looking at other questions I cannot move the location of the accessory view, so it appears this would not be the solution :(

Comment: One of the unfortunate points about UITableViewCell (actually, its an advantage in most situations, just not in this one) is that you can't position the accessory view - the table view cell does it for you. As long as the table view is in the correct place, the accessory view should appear at the correct point.

Comment: As the main controller overhangs the menu like on the Facebook style menu it means the accessory view is hidden. Is there a way to access a specific subview added to the Cell?

Comment: There is indeed - the easiest (least messy) way is to do what you were doing before, but instead of keeping the imageview tracked in a variable on the datasource controller, instead keep track of it as an ivar on the cell (which will have to be subclassed), and add it to the content view as before .There's no problem I can see with doing that, its purely a case of keeping track of the image view inside that cell.

Comment: Ok, would you recommend subclassing the cell and building the cell in storyboard as opposed to all through code? That way I can add the image to the cell in the storyboard link to an outlet and control it as previously? (is this what you mean by keep track of it as an ivar on the cell... I am not familiar with that term, sorry)

Comment: It should be easier to do in code - I'll edit the code above to do that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29682/discussion-between-david-doyle-and-stuartm)

Comment: You are geuinienly my hero! Thanks, I have been looking at this for most the day trying different ways to figure this out. All I needed was to subclass UITableViewCell in the end which is great! I am going to further look into making the cells in Storyboard so that they are visual in there as well per this tutorial - http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/customizing-uitableview-cell/ - in case of use to anyone else. Thanks David